# Changing colour for row in php + access

Tags: php, html, sql, colors

Hi I'm trying to add colour to the specific rows that have a status of O and P.
I have 8 different columns in this display page (status being one of them)

So far my code looks like this:

```
echo"<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='white'>";
if ($editmode == 1)
echo "<td valign='top'><Center><font  face='Arial' size = 2><img src='closedlock.gif' alt='Closed for editing' width='30%'></td>";
else
//  echo "<td><center><img src='openlock.gif' alt='Open for editing' border='0' width='30%'></td>";
echo "<td><center><font  face='Arial' size = 2>$trimref</font></td>";
echo "<td><Center><font  face='Arial' size = 2>".$dateshow1."</td>";
 echo "<td><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2>".$logtime."</td>";

 if (strcmp($userlogged,$fullusername) == 0 && $editmode <> 1 )
 {
 //window.open('opslog.php?ID=$IgnMsgID','opslogwindow$IgnMsID' ,'menubar =0,width=1024,height=750')
echo "<td BGCOLOR='red'><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"openopslog($IgnMsgID)\"><font color='blue'><b><U>".$loggeduser."</u></font></b></a></td>";

 }
 else if  ((($status == 'O'|| $status == 'P' ) && $resvalid == 0) && $editmode <> 1)
 {
     //onclick=\"window.open('opslog.php?ID=$IgnMsgID','opslogwindow$IgnMsID' ,'menubar =0,width=1024,height=750')
echo "<td BGCOLOR='red'><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2><a href=\"javascript:void(0)\" onclick=\"openopslog($IgnMsgID)\"><font color='blue'><b><U>".$loggeduser."</u></font></b></a></td>";

     }

 else
     echo "<td><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2>".$loggeduser."</td>";

    echo "<td align='left'><font face='Arial' size = 2>".$notes."</td>";

      echo "<td><Center><font face='Arial' size = 2>".$loc."</td>";
```

Unfortunately the output of this is not correct.  It only makes the Initials column red of all the P and O status alerts instead of the entire row being red.  Does anyone have any suggestions in which I can get this code to display any row with status alerts P and O to be red.  Thanks

Comment: The 90's called and want their `<font>` back...

Comment: I'm editing an old file.

Comment: if you want a row to be red, you'll have to apply a style to the whole row. e.g. EVERY `<td>` in it, or at the `<tr>` level.

Answer (score 0):

Set the background color for the `<tr>` tag not the `<td>`
example:

```
if ($status == 'O'|| $status == 'P' ){
   echo"<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='red'>";
}else{
   echo"<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='white'>";
};
```

or using a ternary operation like below:

```
  echo "<tr valign='top' BGCOLOR='".(($status == 'O'|| $status == 'P' )?"red":"white")."'>");
```